# Cron task inside container from host

Tags: docker, cron, containers, cron-task

I am trying a cron task inside a container from host but with no luck. From the host I am adding the following line on `crontab -e`

```
* * * * * docker exec -it sample_container bash -c 'touch /selected/directory/temp$(date +%H-%M)'
```

But this is not working. Interestingly, when I run the command independently outside crontab it is successfully executing. Can anyone explain what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: when debugging such problems with cron, you should look for errors in your local system mails or redirect those to your real mail by adding `MAILTO=yourmail@yourdomain.com` on top of your crontab file.

---

There are 2 problems with your crontab command

## TLDR; the fixed cron expression

```
* * * * * docker exec sample_container bash -c 'touch /selected/directory/temp$(date +\%H-\%M)'
```

## % has a special meaning in crontab

From `man -s 5 crontab`

> Percent-signs (`%`) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (`\`), 
>   will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the 
>   first `%` will be sent to the command as standard input.

So you will need to escape those `%` signs in your date format string

## Cron does not allocate a tty

Cron does not allocate a tty whereas your are trying to use one when executing your command (i.e. the `-t` option to `docker exec`). The command will therefore fail with the error `the input device is not a TTY`

You do not need to go interactive (`-i`) nor to allocate a tty for this command to do its job anyway, so you have to drop those options to launch it from cron.

Comment: Spot on! Thank you for nicely explaining the problem and providing a short and quick solution.